# HTML why is the function drop being called four time instead of just once?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

Hello I am trying to build a web app that uses HTML's drag and drop built in functionality. One problem I am running into is when I drop one item into another the on drop function is being called four times instead of just once. Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong or tell how I can fix it to be only called once? Thanks!

HTML, all divs are exactly like this one but with different Id's

```
<div id="Main" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" data-sqlId="0">
```

Javascript

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if(ev.target.getAttribute("data-sqlId")!=null){
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        moves.push({dropped:{id:data, sqlId:document.getElementById(data).getAttribute("data-sqlId")}, target:{id:ev.target.id, sqlId:ev.target.getAttribute("data-sqlId")}});
    }
    console.log(moves);
}
```

A bit of explanation to the other code that does not have to do with the drag and drop functionality. When dropped I first check to see if the div had the property "data-sqlId" to see if it is a div I want others to be able to be dropped into. Once that passes I save two properties of each the div being dropped and the target div. These are saved to a global array. I know the drop is being called four times instead of once because those values get added to the global array four times instead of just once. If worse comes to worse I can just have a checker that when I loop through the global array only execute every fourth item, but Id really prefer just to figure out why its being called four times. Thanks!!

JSFiddle with code
https://jsfiddle.net/AwesomeTN/sk1d8jsm/

Comment: Can you make a [stack snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0) or jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Im having troubles getting the drag and drop to even work on the JSFiddle

Comment: I added a JSFiddle with my code, but I can not get it to even drag and drop at all

Comment: The fiddle gets lots of undefined function errors because you use `onLoad` instead of `No Wrap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once preventDefault has been called it will remain in effect
>   throughout the remainder of the event's propagation.

That is preventDefault does not stop events bubbling up through the DOM.

I would suggest trying `ev.stopPropagation()` instead of (or as well as) `ev.preventDefault()`. Unfortunately the fiddle didn't work when I visited so I was unable to test the answer.

---

Updated: *stopPropagation* spelling corrected above.

After issuing  `stopPropagation` calls after those to `preventDefault`, the number of calls to `drop` reduced to the single call expected per operation in off-line testing. A reason for multiple calls was that you added category 2 and 3 elements as children of the category 1 element, and drop events were indeed bubbling up the DOM.

(As an observation also note that HTML5 id values must not contain spaces so "Container x" patterns are syntactically invalid as element ids).